# MATLAB — How to eliminate equal matrices that are created randomly inside loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, random, equality

The code segment I'm working on is given below:

```
 NphaseSteps = 6;
 phases = exp( 2*pi*1i * (0:(NphaseSteps-1))/NphaseSteps );
 i = 1;
 while i <= 10  %number of iterations
     ind = randi([1 NphaseSteps],10,10);
     inField{i} = phases(ind);
     save('inField.mat', 'inField')
     i = i + 1;
 end
```

Now, what I want is to keep track of these randomly created matrices "inField{i}" and eliminate the ones that are equal to each other. I know that I can use "if" condition but since I'm new to programming I don't know how to use it more efficiently so that it doesn't take too much time. So, I need your help for a fast working program that does the job. Thanks in advance.

---

My actual code segment (after making the changes suggested by @bisherbas) is the following. Note that I actually want to use the variable "inField" inside the loop for every random created matrix and the loop advances only if the result satisfies a specific condition. So, I think the answer given by @bisherbas doesn't really eliminate the equal inField matrices ***before*** they are used in the calculation. This is, of course, my fault since I didn't declare that in the beginning.

```
NphaseSteps = 6;
phases = exp( 2*pi*1i * (0:(NphaseSteps-1))/NphaseSteps );
nIterations = 5;
inField = cell(1,nIterations);
i = 1;
j = 1;
while i <= nIterations % number of iterations
    ind = randi([1 NphaseSteps],TMsize,TMsize);   
    tmp = phases(ind);
    idx = cellfun(@(x) isequal(x,tmp),inField);
    if ~any(idx)
        inField{i} = tmp;
    end
    j = j+1;
    outField{i} = TM * inField{i};
    outI = abs(outField{i}).^2;
    targetIafter{i} = abs(outField{i}(focusX,focusY)).^2;
    middleI = targetIafter{i} / 2;

    if (max(max(outI)) == targetIafter{i})...
            && (   sum(sum((outI > middleI).*(outI < max(max(outI))))) == 0   )
        save('inFieldA.mat', 'inField')
        i = i + 1;
    end


    if mod(j-1,10^6) == 0
        fprintf('The number of random matrices tried is: %d million \n',(j-1)/10^6)
    end

end
```

---

Additionally, I've written a seemingly long expression for my loop condition:

```
if (max(max(outI)) == targetIafter{i})...
            && (   sum(sum((outI > middleI).*(outI < max(max(outI))))) == 0   )
        save('inFieldA.mat', 'inField')
        i = i + 1;
end
```

Here I want a maximum element at some point (focusX, focusY) in the outField matrix. So the first condition decides whether the focus point has the maximum element for the matrix. But I additionally want all other elements to be smaller than a specific number (middleI) and that's why the second part of the if condition is written. However, I'm not very comfortable with this second condition and I'm open to any helps.

Comment: To speed up identity comparisons between matrices you could for example calculate sum for each matrix in each step, and compare more precisely (`all(A == B)`) only those matrices that have the same sum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NphaseSteps = 6;
phases = exp( 2*pi*1i * (0:(NphaseSteps-1))/NphaseSteps );
i = 1;
inField = cell(1,NphaseSteps);
while i <= NphaseSteps  %number of iterations
    ind = randi([1 NphaseSteps],NphaseSteps,NphaseSteps);
    tmp = phases(ind);
    idx = cellfun(@(x) isequal(x,tmp),inField);
    if ~any(idx)
        inField{i} = tmp;
    end
    save('inField.mat', 'inField')
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Read more on `cellfun` here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html

Comment: thanks for your answer but I've intentionally given a small piece of my code segment by assuming that any solution will help. But now I'm not sure whether your answer solves my problem or not. To make it clear I'll edit my problem with more details in a few minutes.